# how to fix invalid geometries in a layer for using it in the QNEAT3 plugin in qgis?

Tags: qgis

as I´m currently working with accessibilites in QGIs I´m using the QNEAT3 plugin and "Iso-Area as Polygons (from Layer)". After running it without any problems using shapes from an open data source I had to create own shapes using OSM data and I always received this error message:

[QNEAT3Algorithm] This is a QNEAT3 Algorithm: 'Iso-Area as Polygons (from Layer)'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users/Nutzer/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\QNEAT3\algs\IsoAreaAsPolygonsFromLayer.py", line 225, in processAlgorithm
input_coordinates = getListOfPoints(startPoints)
File "C:\Users/Nutzer/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\QNEAT3\Qneat3Utilities.py", line 94, in getListOfPoints
return [f.geometry().asPoint() for f in qgsfeatureiterator]
File "C:\Users/Nutzer/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\QNEAT3\Qneat3Utilities.py", line 94, in 
return [f.geometry().asPoint() for f in qgsfeatureiterator]
ValueError: Null geometry cannot be converted to a point.

Execution failed after 0.19 seconds

I expected that after this I fixed the geometires and I won´t receive the same error message.
My (unsuccessful) workaround approaches were this:

- checking the geometry using "check validity": no invalid feature were returned, every feature was valid ( I used the QGIS and GEOS methods in the tool)
- running them in smaller subset layers (in hope of merging afterwards)
- re-installing QNEAT3 multiple times
- applying the "fix geometries" and "snap geoemtries to layer" tools on the shapefile

The 4 columns of the attribute table are: osm_id, code, fclass, name

Interestingly using "service Area (from Layer)" works with the same data, but using this way I just receive the iso-lines, whereas polygones are much better for analyzing afterwards.

To be honest at this point I have no clue, what/where the error is and how to solve it properly.
Thank you very much for your help

cheers